# we would be [risking]/[running the risk of] missing

Tags: grammaticality

CONTEXT:

It's now 5:30pm. John and Bill need to get to the railroad station as quickly as possible because they have tickets for train A, which arrives at 6:30pm. Bill's car is slow, so they take John's car, which is fast, and when they're already on their way to the station, Bill says one of the sentences below.

SENTENCES:

1. If we had taken my car instead of yours, we **would be risking missing** the 6:30 train.
2. If we had taken my car instead of yours, we **would be running the risk of missing** the 6:30 train.

QUESTION:

Do the bolded parts work in the above sentences in the context given?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No reason to use a progressive construction for a stative idiom. _We would run the risk of missing the 6:30 train_ means the same thing and is easier to say and understand. Since states are automatically continuous, the progressive is normally not allowed with them (*_He is owning that house_), but when a metaphoric idiom like _run the risk_ 'risk' (v) uses an ordinarily active verb like _run_, the construction is grammatical. It's just that it's unnecessary.

Comment: And for that matter, why use the idiom when _risk_ (v) works just as well and can be either stative or active?

Comment: @John Lawler: Do you mean that the following version is the best in the context given: _If we **had taken** my car instead of yours, we **would risk missing** the 6:30 train_. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea which one is the best. That would depend on the speaker and addressee and their relationship.